# How can I figure out where all these extra sqlite3 selects are being generated in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, profiling, sqlite

I'm trying to figure out where a whole pile of extra queries are being generated by my rails app. I need some ideas on how to tackle it. Or, if someone can give me some hints, I'd be grateful.

I get these:

```
  SQL (1.0ms)    SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'

  SQL (0.8ms)    SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'

  SQL (0.8ms)    SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'
```

repeated over and over on every request to the DB (as much as 70 times for a single request)

I tried installing a plugin that traced the source of the queries, but it really didn't help at all. I'm using the hobofields gem, dunno if that is what's doing it but I'm somewhat wedded to it at the moment

Any tips on hunting down the source of these extra queries?

Comment: Are you in development mode? Probably Rails is reloading information about tables in development.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing as you. It only occurs for me when using sqlite (not mysql). And it *only* shows these queries in the log when there is an application error that gets rescued.

Comment: Yes I was in development mode and I did not see these logged in production, but that's not really the point. It's really hard to read the log when the screen fills with meaningless garbage. It's also worrisome - is there any impact in production? Is it the result of poor coding that these extra database calls are happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at ActiveRecord gem in connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb on line 173 (I'm using ActiveRecord 3.0.7) you have a function called tables that generates the exact query you posted:

`SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'`

In development mode this function gets called for every table from your database, on every request.
In production this function gets called only once, when the server starts, and the result is cached.

---

In development for each request rails looks into your database to see what columns each table has so it can generate methods on your models like "find_by_name". Since in production is unlikely that your database changes, rails does this lookup only on server start.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Now I'll just need to figure out how to prevent these queries from showing up in the log since it makes debugging painful - but at least now I have a better idea how to hunt it down next time I run into it. It's not something on my radar anymore though.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to tell this without look into the Code.

but i am sure you write your query in a certain loop

```
for i in 0..70
  SqliteMaster.find(:all, :conditions=>["type=? and not name=?", 'table', 'sqlite_sequesnce'])
end
```

So my advice is that to check all the methods which gets called after requesting certain method and look whether the query called in a loop.

Comment: No - that's not happening in the code anywhere. It's all under-the-hood (rails magic) stuff. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532814/how-do-i-turn-off-the-sqlite3-sqlite-master-logging-in-rails) seems to be heading in the right direction. I'd prefer to understand _why_ there are so many redundant calls though.

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen this appearing in my logs when I do a search with the metasearch gem but ONLY in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is caused by the plugin `acts-as-taggable-on`.

It will check if the table or the cache column exists.