# How do I turn off the sqlite3 'sqlite_master' logging in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, sqlite

My development log fills up with

> SELECT name  FROM sqlite_master  WHERE
>   type = 'table' AND NOT name =
>   'sqlite_sequence'

I'd like to turn off the sqlite_master queries in sqlite3, so that I only see the interesting queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it. Perhaps there are better options.

Tested only on Rails 2.3.8.

I added a log_info method to the SQLiteAdapter class in the activerecord gem, which overrides the same method in AbstractAdapter.

```
      def log_info(sql, name, ms)
        unless sql.match(/sqlite_master/)
          if @logger && @logger.debug?
            name = '%s (%.1fms)' % [name || 'SQL', ms]
            @logger.debug(format_log_entry(name, sql.squeeze(' ')))
          end
        end
      end
```

so, any sql statement that contains 'sqlite_master' is not logged.

Comment: This works great! I've created a Rails plugin that implements this, though in a little more flexible way. It's at https://github.com/DavidMikeSimon/shutup_sqlite

Comment: Update: above plugin is now a fancy gem that works on both Rails 2 and 3.